# Is it possible to require only 3 out of 4 segments defined in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, global-shop-solutions

I need to build a regex for a password requirement. The requirements are:

Password must be a minimum of 8 characters and contain ***at least 3 out of 4 of the following:***

1. Upper case
2. Lower case
3. Number
4. Special character

I don't know much about regex. I understand the concept, but I've never heard of a way to specifically only require 3 out of 4 of the parts you define. Below is what I have so far. I know that the `?` after each positive lookahead means that it allows 0 or 1 occurrence of the specified character class, but how do I require a minimum of 3 out of my 4 requirements?

```
^(?=(.*[A-Z])?)(?=(.*[a-z])?)(?=(.*\d)?)(?=(.*\W)?).{8,}$
```

**Update:** the other answer linked to this question (probably) achieves the same result, but the given answer here is much cleaner and more elegant. I would suggest opening this question back up so that future readers get a more modern solution.

Comment: If you want to match 3 out of 4, perhaps it would be easier to test all requirements separately instead of creating a long regex with lookaheads.

Comment: Write 4 different regular expressions, each missing one of the criteria. Then combine them with `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this in a single regex **without repeating** conditions and without using any lookahead:

```bash
^(?:[a-z]()|\d()|[A-Z]()|[^\n\w]()){8,}(?:\1\2(?:\3|\4)|\3\4(?:\1|\2))$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/toEPBm/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`:
- `(?:`:

  - `[a-z]()`: Match an lowercase letter and an empty capture #1
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d()`: Match a digit and an empty capture #2
  - `|`: OR
  - `[A-Z]()`: Match an uppercase letter and an empty capture #3
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^\n\w]()`: Match a special letter and an empty capture #4
- `){8,}`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 8+ times
- `(?:\1\2(?:\3|\4)|\3\4(?:\1|\2))`: In this non-capture group we are making sure that any 3 empty groups were matched earlier
- `$`: End

Comment: What does `[^\n\w]` mean? Does it mean don't accept newline character but do accept other special characters?

Comment: Yes that's right... it means all non-word characters except line break.

Comment: Is it common practice to exclude newline? Does it just cause problems?

Comment: Usually we dom't match line breaks as line break indicates end of input.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you so so so much!! Do you mind upvoting my question so that future readers can be directed to your answer? Your answer is better than the one linked to my question

Comment: I had already upvoted your question yesterday before even answering.

Comment: Also in what language/tool are you using this regex?

Comment: Not sure. This is to be inserted into the Password Reg Exp field of a program called Global Shop Solutions